# Find and use already embedded font?

Tags: itext7

I have create a PDF file with Adobe Illustrator that I have loaded into memory with itext7 pdfreader.

That PDF file already contains a embedded font named "Lato (Embedded)" Encoding:Ansi.

How do create a PDFFont object out of it so I and can use it to draw additional paragraphs?

Comment: *"That PDF file already contains a embedded font"* - iText does not contain a method to enumerate all fonts used somewhere in a PDF, so can you tell where it is? E.g. is it in the resources of some page? Of some specific XObject? Some pattern? Is it a default form resource? If you are not sure, please share the PDF in question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please note that you would only be able to write additional paragraphs with such a fond if the subset contains all the glyphs needed to write the text, or if the font was fully embedded into the PDF.

The solution below works in case the font you want to find is used to write at least one glyph in the content stream of any page in a document (including nested XObjects), and in case you don't have other fonts with similar names in the document.

Here is a small utility class that helps you extract the desired font from a document:

```
private static class FontFinder implements IEventListener {
    private PdfFont suitableFont;
    private String nameToLookFor;

    private FontFinder(String nameToLookFor) {
        this.nameToLookFor = nameToLookFor;
    }

    public static PdfFont findFont(PdfDocument pdfDocument, String fontName) {
        FontFinder finder = new FontFinder(fontName);
        PdfCanvasProcessor processor = new PdfCanvasProcessor(finder);
        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            processor.processPageContent(pdfDocument.getPage(i));
        }
        return finder.suitableFont;
    }

    @Override
    public void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
        if (data instanceof TextRenderInfo) {
            PdfFont curFont = ((TextRenderInfo) data).getFont();
            String fontName = curFont.getFontProgram().getFontNames().getFontName();
            if (fontName != null && fontName.contains(nameToLookFor)) {
                suitableFont = curFont;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<EventType> getSupportedEvents() {
        return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(EventType.RENDER_TEXT));
    }
}
```

You will need to open the `PdfDocument` in stamping mode (passing both `PdfReader` and `PdfWriter` to the constructor).

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inFile), new PdfWriter(outFile));
```

Then you can fetch your font in the following way (make sure result is not null):

```
PdfFont font = FontFinder.findFont(pdfDocument, "Lato");
```

After that you can use that `font` instance to draw any content, e.g. by passing it to `setFont` method of `Paragraph`, `Div` and so on.